# How do I make the the 2nd list item active in an Elementor Pro widget?

Tags: jquery

I am using elementor pro's portfolio widget. As standard, the filter bar comes with a filter that displays all the cards below, now I have managed to remove this li from the front end by using display none. However, the site still shows all the cards. I had the idea to use this code to make the second list item active:

`jQuery('.elementor-portfolio__filters li:nth-child(2)').addClass('elementor-active');`

Alas, this hasn't worked. I'm not sure if there is a way to make this code run and overwrite any other jQuery?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the HTML on which that script is acting. See [ask].

Comment: In what way hasn't it worked? Is the class being applied? Is it being applied to the wrong element? Are you running the script after DOM load (so the elements are available)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working fine check your html.

```js
$('.myClass li:nth-child(2)').addClass('newClass');
```

```css
.newClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='myClass'>
  <ol>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```